# Double group by in cakePhp

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, group-by

How can I reproduce the following query with cakePhp *find()* and *conditions*?

```
SELECT a, SUM(bTotal) as fullTotal FROM
  (SELECT a, SUM(b) * c as bTotal FROM Table1
  GROUP BY a)
GROUP BY a
```

In generally how can I write nested groups in cakePhp?

**Edit**:

I can write it with single group by:

```
$results = $this->Vote->find('all', array('fields' => array('Choice.Answer', '(COUNT(Vote.id) * User.voteMultipler) AS voteTotal', 'choice_id', 'user_id'),
                                          'group' => 'choice_id, Vote.user_id',));
```

I would like to group and sum the result by *Answer*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you subquery needs the `alias` to `GROUP BY` again

```
SELECT q.a, SUM(q.bTotal) as fullTotal FROM
  (SELECT a, SUM(b) * c as bTotal FROM Table1
  GROUP BY a) q
GROUP BY q.a
```

In cakephp

```
$this->YourModel->query(' SELECT q.a, SUM(q.bTotal) as fullTotal FROM
      (SELECT a, SUM(b) * c as bTotal FROM Table1
      GROUP BY a) q
    GROUP BY q.a');
```

OR

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class MYModel extends Model {

    public function myfunction()
    {
        return $this->query(' SELECT q.a, SUM(q.bTotal) as fullTotal FROM
          (SELECT a, SUM(b) * c as bTotal FROM Table1
          GROUP BY a) q
        GROUP BY q.a'); 

    }
}
```